# Way to query nearby location base on Latitude, Longitude and Radius

Tags: java, json, algorithm, api

For example, I have a JSON database like this:

```
[
  {
    "address": "America",
    "location": {
      "lng": 106.669633,
      "lat": 10.771883
    },
    "name": "724 (100) Pyrmon"
  },
  {
    "address": "America",
    "location": {
      "lng": 106.668821,
      "lat": 10.767997
    },
    "name": "900 (100) Glassdor"
  },
  {
    "address": "328A, Đường Lê Hồng Phong, Ward 1, Quận 10, TP.HCM, Việt Nam",
    "location": {
      "lng": 106.676276,
      "lat": 10.763239
    },
    "name": "Booking Office Of Phuong Trang Buslines"
  },
  {
    "address": "America",
    "location": {
      "lng": 106.690329,
      "lat": 10.768556
    },
    "name": "Opposite Pyrmont"
  },
  {
    "address": "America",
    "location": {
      "lng": 106.691759,
      "lat": 10.763937
    },
    "name": "150 Washington"
  },
  {
    "address": "America",
    "location": {
      "lng": 106.681683,
      "lat": 10.76965
    },
    "name": "596 - 598 Nguyễn Đình Chiểu"
  },
  {
    "address": "America",
    "location": {
      "lng": 106.690158,
      "lat": 10.77509
    },
    "name": "17 Bà Huyện Thanh Quan"
  },
  {
    "address": "America",
    "location": {
      "lng": 106.699749,
      "lat": 10.774052
    },
    "name": "101 Jase"
  },
  {
    "address": "America",
    "location": {
      "lng": 106.682621,
      "lat": 10.778547
    },
    "name": "274 Lost Region"
  },
  {
    "address": "America",
    "location": {
      "lng": 106.67305,
      "lat": 10.765617
    },
    "name": "66 Office Base"
  },
  {
    "address": "America",
    "location": {
      "lng": 106.689733,
      "lat": 10.763817
    },
    "name": "118 Yen The"
  },
  {
    "address": "America",
    "location": {
      "lng": 106.69313,
      "lat": 10.765497
    },
    "name": "112 Glangdie"
  },
]
```

Now I have to make an algorithm (in any programming language, if in Java, it will be good) that will input the latitude, longitude, and the distance D . The output will be JSON data that contain the information of nearby places that have the distance to the input distance smaller than D .

I have researched about this algorithm, especially on Wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance#Singularities_and_discontinuity_of_latitude.2Flongitude.

But I cannot find a way to query from the database, if the database is **BIG**, I have to query each row(or each JSON Object in this case) to compare with the chosen location, that will be a very slow performance.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reduce comparisons by filtering locations inside circumscribed square around circle with input radius. In SQL it looks like: `WHERE lng>=(:lng - :radius) AND lng<=(:lng + :radius) AND lat>=(:lat - :radius) AND lat<=(:lat + :radius)`, where `:lng`, `:lat` - input coordinates, `:radius` - input radius in radians.